# Unable to retrieve correct values from deployed contract in hardhat

Tags: javascript, solidity, hardhat

I have created a simpleStorage contract and deploying it using hardhat, everything is working fine but in there is a store function to change the value of a variable. After executing it, when I am retrieveing value, it is not giving me updated value, but the default value.

This is my contract

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    //this line defines the start of a contract
    uint256 favouriteNumber = 7;
    People[] public people;

    mapping(string => uint256) public nametonum;

    struct People {
        uint256 favouriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    function store(uint256 _favouriteNumber) public virtual {
        favouriteNumber = _favouriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return favouriteNumber;
    }

    function addperson(string memory _name, uint256 _favouriteNumber) public {
        people.push(People(_favouriteNumber, _name)); //push function of array, creating struct without{}
        nametonum[_name] = _favouriteNumber;
    }
}
```

and this my deploy script

```
const { ethers, run, network } = require("hardhat")

async function main() {
    const simpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
        "SimpleStorage"
    )
    console.log("Deploying... Please wait")
    const simpleStorageContract = await simpleStorageFactory.deploy()
    await simpleStorageContract.waitForDeployment()
    console.log(
        `Deployed contract to: ${(
            await simpleStorageContract.getAddress()
        ).toString()}`
    )
    if (network.config.chainId === 11155111 && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY)
        await simpleStorageContract.deploymentTransaction().wait(6)
    await verify((await simpleStorageContract.getAddress()).toString(), [])

    const currentValue = await simpleStorageContract.retrieve()
    console.log(currentValue.toString())

    const changeNumberResponse = await simpleStorageContract.store("10")
    changeNumberResponse.wait()
    const updatedValue = await simpleStorageContract.retrieve()
    console.log(updatedValue.toString())
}

async function verify(contractAddress, args) {
    console.log("Verifying Contract...")
    try {
        await run("verify:verify", {
            address: contractAddress,
            constructorArguments: args,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.message.toLowerCase().includes("already been verified")) {
            console.log("Already verified!")
        } else {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((eroor) => {
        console.error(eroor)
        process.exit(1)
    })
```

updated value is not getting changed value after store function call
response--

```
Deploying... Please wait
Deployed contract to: 0xDA63Fc7a82d1eD19b8cC301206AaFC4e56Fd9C75
Verifying Contract...
Successfully submitted source code for contract
contracts/SimpleStorage.sol:SimpleStorage at 0xDA63Fc7a82d1eD19b8cC301206AaFC4e56Fd9C75
for verification on the block explorer. Waiting for verification result...

Successfully verified contract SimpleStorage on the block explorer.
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xDA63Fc7a82d1eD19b8cC301206AaFC4e56Fd9C75#code

7
7
```

Please help!